# Detect what script made change to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have some html form elements on a page and some script is changing them when the page loads. Something is removing their IDs. I don't know how or why but I need to get to the bottom of it. It's as simple as this:

```
<p>
    <input id="depSymbol" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Symbol" />
    <button id="symCheck" class="wpsm-button white small">check</button></p>
<p>
    <input id="depTimeframe" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Timeframe (5, 15, 1H, 1D)" />
</p>
```

This is on a wordpress site. I think one of the plugins I installed might be causing this but it could be something else. There are too many possible causes. For that reason, I need to know: Is there something in dev tools I can use to see what scripts are affecting changes to the DOM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Chrome Dev tools opened, right click on the element and choose `Break on attribute modifications`. Then refresh the page. It should break into the script that's responsible for modifying the ID.

[image]

Comment: once paused in the breakpoint, the call stack can be expanded and browsed, and the filenames performing the action will be listed.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was actually server-side but your answer is the right one and a great ability I didn't know about. Thanks